# Purely inseparable extension of algebraic function field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field with $\operatorname{char}(K) = p > 0$ and with the property that $[K:K^p] < \infty$.
Let $F/K$ be an algebraic function field, i.e there is an element $x \in F$ which is transcendental over $K$ and $F/K(x)$ is a finite field extension. Assume that $F/K(x)$ is separable.

It can be shown that $F/F^{p^n}$ is a finite, purely inseparable field extension with $[F:F^{p^n}] \geq p^n$. If $K$ is perfect, then $[F:F^{p^n}] = p^n$.

When $K$ is not perfect, one can consider $F' := F^{p^n} K$. Using the fact that $F/K$ is separably generated, one can prove that $[F:F'] \leq p^n$.

But do we have $[F:F'] = p^n$?

---

Update: I may have a way to prove it, but I need to know if there is a mistake.

Since $F/K(x)$ is separable by the assumption, we can write $F = K(x, y)$. Consider the subfield $K(x, y^{p^n})$ of $F$. It contains $K(x)$, hence $F/K(x, y^{p^n})$ is separable. On the other hand, it is easy to see that $F/K(x, y^{p^n})$ is purely inseparable (of degree $\leq p^n$). Hence $F = K(x, y^{p^n})$.

Now $F^{p^n} = K^{p^n}(x^{p^n}, y^{p^n})$ and $F' = F^{p^n}K = K(x^{p^n}, y^{p^n})$.
We have $$[F:F'] = \frac{[F:K(x^{p^n})]}  {[F': K(x^{p^n})]} = \frac{[F:K(x)] \cdot [K(x) : K(x^{p^n})]} {[F': K(x^{p^n})]} = \frac{[F:K(x)] \cdot p^n} {[F': K(x^{p^n})]} = \frac{[K(x, y^{p^n}):K(x)] \cdot p^n} {[K(x^{p^n}, y^{p^n}): K(x^{p^n})]} \cdot$$ 
In order to see $[F:F'] = p^n$, we only need to show $[K(x, y^{p^n}):K(x)] \geq [K(x^{p^n}, y^{p^n}): K(x^{p^n})]$, because it is easy to see $[F:F'] = [K(x, y^{p^n}) :K(x^{p^n}, y^{p^n})] \leq p^n$.

Now let $f(T) = \sum_{i=0}^n f_i(x)T^i \in K(x)[T] $ be the minimal polynomial of $y$ over $K(x)$. Then $f(y) = \sum_{i=0}^n f_i(x)y^i = 0$. Hence $\sum_{i=0}^n \tilde{f_i}(x^{p^n})(y^{p^n})^i = 0$, here $\tilde{f_i}$'s are obtained from $f_i$'s by raising their coefficients to the $p^n$ power. This shows that $[K(x^{p^n}, y^{p^n}): K(x^{p^n})] \leq n = [K(x, y):K(x)] = [K(x, y^{p^n}):K(x)]$ and the proof is done.